# Consume ServiceStack SOAP service from Silverlight application

Tags: soap, servicestack

For the past few days I have been looking at ServiceStack as a replacement for our WCF-based middleware (that exposes SOAP services).

My two main requirements :

- Can be hosted outside of IIS (no problem using `AppHostHttpListenerBase`)
- ServiceStack SOAP interfaces can be consumed from a Silverlight application.

Hosting from a console application works smoothly, but adding a service reference in my Silverlight client gives the following warning:

```
Custom tool warning: Endpoint 'WSHttpBinding_IOneWay' at address 'http://localhost:8080/soap12' is not compatible with Silverlight 5. Skipping...
```

Which makes sense, but I cannot seem to find a way to change the binding to e.g. basicHttpBinding.

Is this possible? I tried various ways to tackle this from `app.config` but no luck so far.

Much obliged in advance,

Robert van Drunen